# Google CDN Connection to CDN create nosuch Key Errors

Tags: google-cloud-storage

i uploaded images to google storage bucket and i am no trying to set the CDN using the load balancer to work.

Storage Status :
Bucket Permissions : Storage Object Viewer - Reader assign to  allUsers ,
Storage Legacy Bucket Reader assign To allUsers

File Status :
Share Public is set and there is a public link

Load Balancer:
Set to path /creatives/* on the host name

but i always get this msg:

```
 <Error>
 <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
 <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
 </Error>
```

what i notice is as soon as i build the path of /creatives/* there is another path build /* direct to the backend service of the auto scale group

am i  missing here any settings?

Comment: This error has nothing to do with permission. This error comes when object URL you are trying to access does not match to any object URL in google bucket. If you have `gsutil` installed then run `ls` or `cat` to display object content like `gsutil ls gs://objectUrl` and verify if an object is present in a bucket or now. Mostly issue is due to wrong object URL getting created.

Comment: Thanks , i wrote the answer myself as this hidden in the logs as you mention. just didn't fully understood the forced static web site host mode google CDN is providing as default

Answer (score 11):

So as i discovered Google CDN + Google http Load balancer works different from other CDN.

with a regular CDN you can direct the origin to you bucket HTTP address and work on the / structure.
for example :
Google CDN Bucket URL:
googleapi.storage.com/my-bucket
Folder structure:
/1/1.jpg

Normal CDN origin will be pointing to googleapi.storage.com/my-bucket
and you will get a new service endpoint for the CDN like:
my-bucket.fastly.cdonservice.com
and this call will work:
my-bucket.fastly.cdonservice.com/1/1.jpg

but on google cloud what you are setting up is a path that is connected to the CDN service that you created on the backend part.
So this is the big difference, lets assume that you created this path rule.
host: www.googlecdnnonexplainedfeautres.com
path: /images/*
service: yourbackendservice (connected to the bucket you want to cache)

so you might assume this should work:
www.googlecdnnonexplainedfeautres.com/images/1/1.jpg.

but NO ..
after digging the logs you will find a 404 on the bucket because google will go and search this path on the bucket:

googleapi.storage.com/my-bucket/images/1/1.jpg.

wait , where did the images came ? i thought its a hook. no google take this as a static website root ( the thing you can check on and off on S3) so here its mandatory.

so how this should work ?

modify the folder structure to be like this :

Google CDN Bucket URL:
googleapi.storage.com/my-bucket

Folder structure:
images/1/1.jpg

and now you are good.

This link should work now :

www.googlecdnnonexplainedfeautres.com/images/1/1.jpg.

so before you commit a bucket to be used as CDN source for google just add another top folder that match with the path you set on the LB.

and of course .. permissions , allUsers , read and etc..

EnjoY!

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've just ended a couple of hours of `NoSuchKey` insanity

Comment: Thank you Meta_data - indeed insane, have been spent > 1h to figure out why, @google really should document this and highlight it!

Comment: Thank you very much, google should really document it.

Comment: oh! Thank you so much! It was really awkward to spend so much hours without solution.

Answer (score 5):

### You can use URL Rewrites to solve this problem.

This may not have existed back in 2017 but there's an option at least as of 2021.

---

Explanation:

The lb's default behavior is to pass the entire path after the host to Cloud Storage. This may seem incorrect, but it's a sane default (How is the load balancer supposed to know what part of the path you want to include or exclude?).

I was facing the same issue.

I connected `mydomain.com/static/*` to my cloud storage bucket `static-assets`.

Upon visiting `mydomain.com/static/static-asset.jpg` the load balancer would request cloud storage for an object with key `static-assets/**static**/static-asset.jpg`.

Since the object's actual key is `static-assets/static-asset.jpg`, this would return a `NoSuchKey` response.

The fix was the rewrite the path prefix of `/static` to `/`.

One way to configure this is through the Cloud Console Load Balancer UI--we can add an advanced path rule to rewrite the prefix.

[image: Cloud Console GUI Showing Path Rule Details]

Please note:

> Important: The rewrite is prepended to the path as is. Full path
> rewrites are not supported. HTTP(S) Load Balancing only implements
> path prefix rewrites. For example, you **can** rewrite:
> `host.name/path1/resource1` to `host.name/path2/resource1`. You *cannot*
> rewrite `host.name/path1/resource1` to `host.name/path1/resource2`.

Read about URL Rewrites [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-url-rewrite).

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Meta_data to create folder is really helpful. But I want to add another solution that does not involve creating folder.

What I want to achieve is that the path with `cat` prefix should show items from "cats" bucket and the path with no prefix should show items from "dogs" bucket.

"Routing rules" > "Advanced host and path rule" can be used here

```
defaultService: projects/<project-name>/global/backendBuckets/dogs
name: path-matcher-2
routeRules:
- description: CatService
  matchRules:
  - pathTemplateMatch: /cat/{trailing_path=**}
  priority: 1
  service: projects/<project-name>/global/backendBuckets/cats
  routeAction:
    urlRewrite:
      pathTemplateRewrite: /{trailing_path}
```

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts#wildcards-regx-dynamic-route