# Google Cloud Load Balancer and Storage Bucket No Such key Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a nodejs website running on Google cloud app engine with a domain connected and SSL setup. The app has a admin panel and the file uploads are currenlty beign sent to a Google cloud bucket. On the load balancer, I made a rule that /upload-media/* points to my bucket and uploaded a test file to the bucket named test.png. When i try to access mydomain.com/upload-media/test.png , it returns a "No such key" error "The specified key does not exist." which i believe the path it's looking for the file is wrong. I've been trying to solve this issue for the past day without any success. I found a few questions here on Stackoverflow, like [Google CDN Connection to CDN create nosuch Key Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113408/google-cdn-connection-to-cdn-create-nosuch-key-errors) , but still getting the error after trying to solutions. I appreciate any inputs.

Tried changing the folder structure, but resulted in same errors.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, **upload-media** must be a folder off of the root of your backend bucket and the test.png must be in it.

```
gs://<bucket>/upload-media/test.png
```

"No such key" simply means the key object (upload-media/test.png) could not be found.